# Border Radius and Java Script

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic

I have a JS file that makes `#nav` a fixed element when it hits the top of the page (to make a floating nav bar that persists regardless of scrolling). When not at the top of the page, `#nav` has rounded corners on the top (border radius top left and top right), which I'd like to disappear when the element is changed to "fixed" This is my code:

```
$(function() {
  // Stick #nav to the top of the window
  var nav = $('#nav');
  var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
  var isFixed = false;
  var $w = $(window);
  $w.scroll(function() {
      var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
      var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
      if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
          nav.css({
              position: 'fixed',
              top: 0,
          });
          isFixed = true;
      }
      else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
      {
          nav.css({
              position: 'static'
          });
          isFixed = false;
      }
  });
});
```

This doesn't work:

```
$(function() {
  // Stick #nav to the top of the window
  var nav = $('#nav');
  var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
  var isFixed = false;
  var $w = $(window);
  $w.scroll(function() {
      var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
      var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
      if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
          nav.css({
              position: 'fixed',
              top: 0,
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px,
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px,
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px,
-moz-border-radius-topright: 0px,
border-top-left-radius: 0px,
border-top-right-radius: 0px
          });
          isFixed = true;
      }
      else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
      {
          nav.css({
              position: 'static'
          });
          isFixed = false;
      }
  });
});
```

How can I edit the border radius values of #nav from my JS?

Comment: is -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px, ever getting hit while debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your best to keep your CSS seperate from your JS. I'd recommend creating a seperate class for the "fixed" version of the element with all of your extra CSS in it, and then removing and adding that class as necessary.

**CSS:**

```
#nav.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  // Stick #nav to the top of the window
  var nav = $('#nav');
  var navHomeY = nav.offset().top;
  var isFixed = false;
  var $w = $(window);
  $w.scroll(function() {
      var scrollTop = $w.scrollTop();
      var shouldBeFixed = scrollTop > navHomeY;
      if (shouldBeFixed && !isFixed) {
          nav.addClass("fixed")
          isFixed = true;
      }
      else if (!shouldBeFixed && isFixed)
      {
          nav.removeClass("fixed")
          isFixed = false;
      }
  });
});
```

Much neater, no?